# After some time, PHP can no longer connect to memcached until memcached is restarted

Tags: php, drupal-7, memcached

For years I've been running a PHP/Drupal 7 site with memcached as the caching backend, running on the same server as PHP (7.3), Apache, and MySQL. Recently, this error has been showing up:

> **Notice:** MemcachePool::getstats(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211, udd 0) failed with: Connection refused (111) in **require_once()** (line **19** of **/usr/local/projects/r/example.com/web/sites/all/modules/memcache-lock.inc**).

This error shows up every few days. Restarting the `memcached` service resolves the issue for a period. I've looked in `/var/log/syslog` for error messages related to `memcached`, but found nothing. I've tried enabling logging in `/etc/memcached.conf` with `logfile /var/log/memcached.log` but the file wasn't created after restarting the service. I'm at a loss of what more to check for.

The server is Ubuntu 16.04 running on DigitalOcean. I've made sure [the memcache Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) is up-to-date.

Comment: Did you check memcache keys integrity or quantity ? maybe memcached needs to be flushed or have less keys entries , usefull thread https://groups.google.com/g/memcached/c/CSnfD_FgzuA?pli=1

Comment: @Fky memcached is setup to automatically evict entries as it runs out of memory. What do you mean by "keys integrity"? And aside from memory limits, should I be worrying about the number of keys/entries?